# Why for logistic regression the error is given by [y ln(sigma(x)) + (1 − y) ln(1 − sigma(x)]

Tags: logistic-regression, linear-regression

Why for logistic regression, with target values 0 or 1, it will not work to take the sum of the squares of the difference between target value and prediction, but rather:
$$
error({\bf w}) = -1/m * \sum_{i=1}^{m} [ y_i \ln (\sigma({x_i})) + (1-y_i) \ln (1 - \sigma({x_i} ) ]
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the log-likelihood:

$\log P(x; w) \equiv \log \prod_i P(x_i | w) = \sum_i \log P(x_i | w)$, where $P(x_i | w) \equiv \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}\sigma(x_i), & y_i =1 \\ 1 - \sigma(x_i), &y_i = 0\end{array} \right.$

Why the log-likelihood? When you have a probabilistic model, such as logistic regression, it's one way (the [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood)) of finding the parameters that fit best. Recall that in logistic regression we are, contrary to the name, trying to *classify* rather than regress, and the MSE is a regression loss; it seeks to minimize the distance from a point, while [we wish to penalize being in the wrong *subspace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification) (the parts that don't correspond to the correct class). If you squint a bit, you can see that the negative log-likelihood minimizes the [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_error_function_and_logistic_regression).

Comment: One way of putting the *why* - if you are 99% certain of a prediction which turns out later to be true, this is 10 times stronger than being 90% certain of an event (think of what you'd be willing to bet), and this is captured by a log-likelihood objective whilst sum of squares difference would prefer you gain from 50% to 60% on some other more marginal example.

Comment: @Emre in your notation, the formula you give would be correct even if I used a function different from the logistic function?

Comment: @NeilSlater would you mind expanding a little more your comment?

Comment: Yes, @user, up until the definition of $P(x_i|w)$.